# Having issue with accessing structure element using arrow notation

Tags: c, structure

I want to print the string "HelloWorld" at the output using the arrow notation.
but it is not working as expected, can someone please point out the errors in this code and help me fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int a ;
    char a[100]="HelloWorld";
}Node;

main(){
    Node *v;
    printf("%s\n",v->a);
}
```

Edit:
I have found the mistakes in my code and understood the points I was confused with, thanks everyone for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  
struct Node {         
int a ;         
char b[100];        
};                          
void main()         
{                   
struct Node tester;            
struct Node* i = &tester;           
strcpy(tester.b,"HelloWorld");            
printf("%s\n",i->b);        
}
```

Comment: To which `Node` does your pointer `v` point to?

Comment: `v` is uninitialized. Where do you expect it to point ?

Comment: I created a structure variable with name Node and also tried creating the instance of Node with same name , is this permissible in C. Also I tried Initializing the struct element a with a predefined value, I hope this is also acceptable in C and then created a pointer "v" to the struct Node inside main. and accessing its element using arrow notation. what should be correct code if I have written wrong code

Comment: Your code is not valid C. You cannot provide an initializer or default value to y type definition. You must initialize during variable definition. Also implicit int declaration is an ancient feature. You should provide correct signature for `main`: `int main(void)`

Comment: You did not define any *variable* with name `Node`. You define a *type* `struct Node` and a *type* `Node` and a *variable* `v` that is pointer to `Node`. Also you cannot define multiple members of a struct with same name `a`. Learning a language is not possible with trial and error. Use some proper learning material

Comment: Try to think about what you're doing.  Reason it out.  You have a pointer.  It's completely uninitialized.  Its value can be anything.  How can it possibly make sense to try to dererference it?  Answer:  It can't.  Initialize it first.  I.e., assign the address of a `Node` to it.  Maybe read a tutorial that describes the proper use of pointers (this problem is more basic than structure pointers - the same thing applies to *all* pointers - they *have* to be initialized before you try to dereference them).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors in your code:

- You cannot provide a value for members in a type definition.
- You have multiple struct members with same name
- You dereference an uninitialized pointer.
- You also don't provide return type for `main` which is deprecated.

That seems as if you try to learn C by trial and error which will never end well.

Your code snippets needs to be changed as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    char text[100];
} Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node *v = malloc(sizeof(*v));
    if (v == NULL)
    {
      perror("Cannot allocate memory");
      exit(1);
    }
    v->value = 123;
    strcpy(v->text, "Hello World");
    printf("%s\n",v->text);
}
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
        int a ;
        char b[100];
        };
        
        
       void main()
        {
            
          struct Node tester;
           struct Node* i = &tester;
          strcpy(tester.b,"HelloWorld");
           printf("%s\n",i->b);
        } `

Comment: I have updated my code and it seems to be working fine, hello @Gerhardh thanks for adding the code and details , I have some questions , is creating the struct variable "Node" and then creating an instance of the same struct with same name "Node" is possible in C

Comment: You should get your wording right. Variables are instances of types. You are talking about defining a *struct type* `Node` and also a *variable* (= instance) `Node`. That is basically possible but unless you hate people (including your future self) why would you ever want to do this? You will not gain anything except confusing people.

Comment: In your code snippet you have invalid signature for `main`. In a hosted environment it must return `int`.